# It's Possible To Render HTML Inside a SQL Server Reporting Services 2008's Report?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've read, that is possible to render HTML inside a SSRS 2008 report making use of the *HTML Markup type* of the textbox control.

I'm trying to render a simple link like:

```
<a href="/destination">My Link</a>
```

So the value of the placeholder would be:

```
="<a href=\"destination\">"My link</a>"
```

But it seems like the *\"* is causing problems. there is a runtime error for using such expression: *The Value expression for the textrun ‘Numbers1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30205] End of statement expected. (rsCompilerErrorInExpression)*

**How do you escape the `"` character inside a expression?**

**Is it possible to render HTML?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\" is how you escape a quote in C#.  SSRS uses VB.NET I believe, so using "" should work.

Comment: Further Note: The HTML is interpreted as styling for the text rendered, not textually.